# Form with tabs - The data insert in tabs are not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form with tabs.

In each tab, there is a section.
The tabs its working, but I can't save the dates.

I insert datas in field's and I click in submit, but it's not working, the only filds saves are the fields in the first tab. (Details)

In case, I can get the value inserted in data_interview, interviewer and attachment.

I cant get the value inserted in name field.

The content insert in other tabs are lost.

[image: a]
![]

There is a part of code:

```
<div class="container">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#main_information" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.main_information') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#personal_data" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.personal_data') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#formation" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.formation') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#idioms_certifications" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.idioms_certifications') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#professional_experience" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.professional_experience') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#other_informations" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.other_informations') %></a></li>
<li><a href="#professional_assessment" data-toggle="tab"><%= t('labels.professional_assessment') %></a></li>
</ul>  


  <%= form_for(@hr_curriculum_intern, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="main_information" class="tab-pane active">

   <div class="container">
     <form role="form">

       <div class="row">
         <label class="col-md-2"><%= t('columns.date_interview')%></label>
     <%#= f.label :date_interview, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
         <div class="col-md-1">
           <%= f.date_select :date_interview %> 
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
         <label class="col-md-2"><%= t('attributes.interviewer')%>*</label>
         <%#= mark_required(@hr_curriculum_intern,:interviewer) %>
     <%#= f.label :interviewer, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
         <div class="col-md-3">
           <%= f.text_field :interviewer, :class => "input-block-level" %>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
         <label class="col-md-2"><%= t('attributes.attachment')%></label>
     <%#= f.label :attachment, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
         <div class="col-md-3">
           <%= f.file_field :attachment, :class => "input-block-level" %> 
         </div>
       </div>           

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="personal_data" class="tab-pane" > 
    <div class="container">
       <form role="form">

       <div class="row">
         <label class="col-md-2"><%= t('attributes.name')%>*</label>
     <%#= f.label :name, :class => "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "input-block-level" %>     
         </div>
       </div>
```

Sorry for my english.

I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of these: `<form role="form">` for a start. the `form_for` is responsible for starting and ending form tags. These extras may well be interrupting the data.